# Interpolating Data Using SciPy

Tags: python, interpolation

I have two arrays of data that correspond to x and y values, that I would like to interpolate with a cubic spline.

I have tried to do this, but my interpolated function doesn't pass through my data points.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

    re = np.array([0.2,2,20,200,2000,20000],dtype = float)
    cd = np.array([103,13.0,2.72,0.800,0.401,0.433],dtype = float)

    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.xlabel( "Reynold's number" )
    plt.ylabel( "Drag coefficient" )
    plt.plot(re,cd,'x', label='Data')

    x = np.linspace(0.2,20000,200000)
    f = interp1d(re,cd,kind='cubic')
    plt.plot(x,f(x))

    plt.legend()

    plt.show()
```

What I end up with looks like this;

[image]

Which is clearly an awful representation of my function. What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result you probably expect (smooth spline on the log axes) by doing this:

```
f = interp1d(np.log(re),np.log(cd), kind='cubic')
plt.plot(x,np.exp(f(np.log(x))))
```

This will build the interpolation in the log space and plot it correctly. Plot your data on a linear scale to see how the cubic has to flip to get the tail on the left hand side.

Comment: Ah, I see why I was getting a 'funny' result now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you are missing is the `log` scaling on your axes. The spline shown is not an unreasonable result given your input data. Try drawing the plot with `plt.xscale('linear')` instead of `plt.xscale('log')`. Perhaps a cubic spline is not the best interpolation technique, at least on the raw data. A better option may be to interpolate on the log of the data insead.

Comment: I think I do have logarithmic axes, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: You do. That is why the fit looks so terrible.